# how do edit complex xml file by sed

Tags: sed, xmlstarlet

this is the structure of xml file:

```
  <test.file>
    <set name="parameter1" serializeAs="String">
      <value>True</value>
    </set>
    <set name="parameter2" serializeAs="String">
      <value>True</value>
    </set>
  </test.file>
```

I want to edit value from True to False for Parameter2
when I use this command:
xmlstarlet ed -u //test.\file/set/value -v False filename
It is updating both value from True to False.
How can I control to edit the value only for name="parameter2"?

Thank u!

Comment: looks like you are new to sed, see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sed/info for learning resources... try something and then ask question if the code you've tried is not working.. coming to xml file editing, sed is not a good fit.. use parsers like xmlstarlet or programming languages like perl/python which have xml modules

Comment: Thanks for your advise! I used xmlstarlet and it works. thank u.

Comment: @שרהנסימי, Oppps. I just now saw your comment(after posting my answer since I was on this page for long time didn't appear on page weird), you could check if that is same like your command or if that helps you here. Cheers.

Comment: I edit the question above with the specific question. who can help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is asking to make changes on a specific tag's value so changed code according to it.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//test.file/set[@name='parameter2']/value" -v "false"  Input_file.xml
```

---

Following `xmlstarlet` command may help you here.

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/test.file/set/value" -v "false"  Input_file.xml
```

To do inplace update into xml file itself use following.

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u  "/test.file/set/value" -v "false"  Input_file.xml
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. it's the same command I used. now I have another issue, see the edited question. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @שרהנסימי, please see my EDIT solution now and let me know?